# finding bases of solutions to ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have these two similar ODE's:
$$ u''' + 6u'' + 12u' + 8u = 0$$ and $$ u''' +6u'' + 12u' +(8+i)u = 0$$

I know that for an $n$-th order ODE there are $n$ lin-indep bases of solutions. And know how to solve for 2nd order, but how would I approach these third-order ones?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Laplace Transform method? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform_applied_to_differential_equations

Comment: They may both be solved via the same method as a second order one. Assume an exponential solution $u = Ae^{\lambda x}$

Comment: For the first one, I was able to use characteristic polynomial to find the bases but I am not sure how to do the same for the second DE

Comment: @Zuriel don't we need initial conditions to use the Laplace Transform method?

Comment: @nyim LT without the Right initial conditions will be headache, but is possible. And I don't see why characteristic polynomial won't be the same for the second one. The only difference is that you have complex number there, you should add your work on the second one to the question and we would be able to help you better

Comment: All the roots of the second polynomial are of the form $\lambda = a + bi$, and there are three of them, each yields a term $u(x) = Ae^{(a+bi)x} = e^{ax}(C\sin{bx}+D\cos{bx})$

Answer (score 0):

***Hint for first equation***

$$u''' + 6u'' + 12u' + 8u = 0$$
Substitute $z=u'+2u$ then the equation becomes sipmly
$$z''+4z'+4z=0$$
Polynome is $R^2+4R+4=(R+2)^2=0 \implies R=-2$
.Then 
$$z=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}$$
Substitute back $z=y'+2y$
$$y'+2y=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}$$
$$(ye^{2x})'=c_1+c_2x$$
integrate
$$(ye^{2x})=c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=e^{-2x}(c_3+c_1x+c_2x^2)}$$

I let you finish the second equation...

Comment: I think I'm getting a similar result but I used the characteristic polynomial

Comment: Thats good too ....@nyim

Comment: I'm not sure how to use characteristic polynomials to find the basis for the second one?

Comment: Polynomial works fine when you know a fatorization...@nyim

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't not add anything to the question after saying you failed in the second equation here is basic explanation to solve Homogenous Linear ODE using characteristic polynomial:

The polynomial will yelled $n$ complex or real roots, let's say one of the roots is: $a+ib$, in this case we will consider $b\ne 0$ because if $b=0$ we have a trivial solution to our purpose.

By the characteristic polynomial way we will have to take $e$ to the power of the roots, in the complex case it is the same: $e^{a+ib}$, or more accurate, $Ae^{a+ib}$. The main problem now is that we want real valued solution, or at least the closest we can get, so we use what Euler taught us: $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\;\;(*)$

Using $(*)$ we get: $Ae^{a+ib}=Ae^ae^{ib}=Ae^a(\cos b+i\sin b)=e^a(C_1\cos b+C_2\sin b)$.

Now in your case, use the roots the characteristic polynomial: $(r+2)^3+i=0$

---

$(*)$ If you want a proof, there is a lot of ways to prove Euler's formula on the internet but the most elegant one I my opinion is: consider the function $g(x)=e^{-ix}(\cos x+i\sin x)$, from this we get $g'(x)=0$, in other words this function is a constant, and $g(0)=1$, hence $e^{-ix}(\cos x+i\sin x)=1\implies e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$